# Path GeoFence in android Between two point

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing, android-geofence

I am beginner in Android Development and I try to develop an Android application in which i want to GEOFence the path. let suppose I create a path A to B by using google directions api and
i assign that path to driver to follow that path.if Driver not follow that path he get the alert message and show him right path to follow.I am not getting any proper example or idea how i can do.please help me to solve my problem with some good example 
here is my  code which i used for create a polyline from source to destination for Google Directions api.

```
MainActivity.XML

public String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters  =str_origin+"&"+"waypoints=optimize:true|"+"&"+"alternatives=true"+"&"+str_dest+"    &"+sensor+"&"+"mode=Driving"+"&"+"key=AIzaSyBM9huE4dOMUE_tBHNaibKd_8nOexVCnag";
    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}
```

Comment: hey buddy. you can not really have a easy way for your problem. this is a google navigation api requirement in your app. and google does not provide a navigation api.

Comment: @Sagar Nayak Than how I can solve my problem.

Comment: you can do this by the use directions api and google maps api . but practically speaking you don't have to do it. this is a makinig of own navigation inside your own app.